# Problemas de layout quebrado nos sprites do meta

Tags: bug, status-pronto, layout

Isto acontece só comigo ou com mais alguém?

Exemplo de imagem com os votos de uma resposta do meta:

<kbd>[image: Imagem zoada 1]</kbd>

Exemplo de imagem com os votos nesta pergunta aqui no meta:

<kbd>[image: Imagem zoada 2]</kbd>

E também isso nas tags:

<kbd>[image: Imagem zoada 3]</kbd>

O que aconteceu com o layout do meta para ficar assim?

Aparentemente os sprites do meta foram convertidos para SVG, enquanto que os do site principal estão em PNG. E as posições dos dois não coincidem.

Eis eles lado a lado (convertido o do meta para PNG para poder adicionar aqui). Observe o desalinhamento entre um e outro:

<kbd>[image: Sprites do site principal]</kbd><kbd>[image: Sprites do meta]</kbd>

Ou seja, os sprites do meta estão erroneamente deslocados em relação com o que deveria ser de acordo com o CSS/JS em 15 pixels para cima na vertical.

Comment: O meu está assim também

Comment: Vixe nem vi que já existia uma pergunta, deletei a minha :p - Tentei Ctrl+F5 (refresh que ignora o cache) pensando ser um problema na atualização deles do CSS, mas não era

Comment: Alguém mexeu no botão de "vertical" do servidor.

Comment: xi, acontecendo aqui pra mim... será que também é culpa do novo design do Code Review? . . . [Site icons misaligned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270001/185667)

Comment: @Victor há também nos comentários... Foi por causa do ajusto do logo.

Comment: E também falta as medalhas no topo da página...

Comment: E não dá para aceitar uma resposta.

Comment: we're investigating. fix will be online asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O bug foi consertado, [tal como anunciado pelo Pawel](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/4599/6) em 27 de novembro.

Answer (score 3):

Há também mais estes problemas:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Não tem medalhas aqui:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>